# Is their anyway to get TLS 1.3 on Nginx without building from source

Tags: rhel, nginx, openssl

Currently running NGINX on redhat 7.7 production webserver, I think I know the answer but I wanted to double check. The issue is I'm trying to get TLS1.3 working.
Below is part of my conf.

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
```

My version of NGINX is `nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
```

If we notice the third line we see `built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`. Which I have come to believe it's the problem.

According to yum I have the latest version of openssl installed.

So it looks like I need to have openssl 1.1.1d -latest version- (September 10, 2019; 5 months ago) and recompile both openssl and NGINX from source.

Is their any way to do this without a recompile from a standard Redhat yum repo and does anybody know when "openssl 1.1.1" and a version of NGINX  compiled with openssl 1.1.1 will be put into a standard Redhat Repo?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [TLS 1.3 is going to be officially available in RHEL 8](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/transport-layer-security-version-13-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8).

Unless someone else has done it for you, getting it running in RHEL 7 would need a recompile of both `openssl` and `nginx` as you mentioned.

You could use the [official Nginx Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) which if I remember have been built for TLS 1.3 for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

The packaged installation is available through [NGINX-MOD](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build) (which is, however, a subscription-ware).

It is a stable NGINX package that is compiled with the latest OpenSSL and a bunch of Cloudflare performance patches.

You can also install things like ModSecurity module, Brotli module, and 30+ dynamic modules from the same repository. Each module is available in its own packages and regularly updated.